# Как в основной форме Отменить backgroundWorker другой формы

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

Ребята. Мне нужно отменить BakgroundWorker из основной формы, которая была запущена в другой форме. Я пытаюсь решить эту проблему с помощью делегатов. Возможно есть другие пути решения? Подскажите пожалуйста! Привожу для примера код главной формы:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm(string FIO)
    {
       //some code
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Canceled;

    private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (Canceled != null)
           Canceled(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Код формы, в которой был запущен backgroundWorker

```
public partial class CarriageForm : Form
{
    public CarriageForm(ToolStripProgressBar toolStripProgressBar1, ToolStripLabel toolStripLabel1)
    {
        //some code
    }

private void CarriageForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progBar.Visible = false;

    if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        progBar.Visible = true;
        progBar.Maximum = GetTotalRecords();
        string GetCarriage = "Select dc.ID, dc.CarNumber [Номер вагона],dc.AXIS [Осность],do.ID [OwnerID], do.Name [Собственник],do.FullName [Собственник полное наименование] From d__Carriage dc Left Join d__Owner do on do.ID = dc.Owner_ID";

        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm(null);
        mainForm.Canceled += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Button2_Click);

        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(GetCarriage);
    }

    //BackgroundWorker1_DoWork...

    //BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged...

    //BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted..

public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
            {
                // Stop the Background Thread execution
                Application.UseWaitCursor = false;
                System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
                progBar.Value = 0;
                progBar.Visible = false;
                TlStpLabel.Text = "Пользователь умышленно отменил";
            }
        }
}
```

Для наглядности

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: пример работы]

Для `BW` второй формы нужно выставить `Modifiers` в `Public`

[image: назначение свойства]

При запуске второй формы получаем ссылку на BW, и используем эту ссылку для отмены работы.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //для ссылки на Bw второго окна
    private BackgroundWorker _bw;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Первая форма";

        _buttonOpenForm.Click += ButtonOpenForm_Click;
        _buttonStopBgW.Click += ButtonStopBgW_Click;
    }

    private void ButtonOpenForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Owner = this;
        //передаем ссылку на Bw
        _bw = form2._backgroundWorker;
        form2.Show();
    }

    private void ButtonStopBgW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //проверяем, что Bw есть и что он работает
        //тогда отменяем
        if (_bw != null && _bw.IsBusy) _bw.CancelAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать вспомогательный сервис, который будет содержать все методы по работе с воркерами, создавать новые отменять старые и тд. 
Если хочется проще, то сделать переменную воркера публичной, и пошарить ссылку на дочернюю форму с главной. То есть в коде главной форме обратится к дочерней, и ее воркеру.

Comment: Приведите пример, для ясности